# Creating an ontology for dataframe with more than two columns

Tags: r, tree, ontology, dendrogram, ggraph

I am trying to create a tree/ontology/dendrogram (using either ggraph or igraph) from a dataset that has three columns and thus three distinct branches:

```
df <- data.frame(
           parent = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"), 
           child1 = c("ax", "ax", "ay", "bx", "by", "cx"),
           child2 = c("ax1", "ax2", "ay1", "bx1", "by1", "cx1")
           )
```

How do I go about creating edge and node columns when I have three levels to the hierarchy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package **collapsibleTree** can be used for trees with multiple nodes.

```
collapsibleTree::collapsibleTree(df, hierarchy = c("parent", "child1"), height = 600, width = 600, collapse = FALSE)
```